# Android how to save a pizza order?

Tags: android

I have an application, I get a long list of pizzas here, this is a web service. (get_all_pizza.php)

In android what is the best way to store the orders?

```
pizza name1 count: 3 price xxx $ 
pizza name2 count: 1 price xxx $
```

only SQL, or something else?

thanks, Leslie

Comment: You want to save client-side or server-side?

Comment: i d like to upload the orders to a server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL and devising the schema is one of the best options that you have.